# cloudStorageAccount

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

before migrating to 2.0, the code below worked (type CloudStorageAccount was in namespace StorageClient):

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));


var roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = cloudStorageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(
    RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
    RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
    RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);
```

StorageClient was removed in 2.0, so now I have to use

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount
```

, bit this type does not have the method CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager

So how can I get the instance returned by CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager previously, as I use it for my Performance Counters and Logs

Answer (score 5):

It certainly looks like there was a change at 2.0 and doesn't act like an extension method any more - which means you may not need the CloudStorageAccount you have at the top I just ran into this myself.

Try this:

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                       RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));

var roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = CloudAccountDiagnosticMonitorExtensions.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(
            RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString),
            RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is first include the following name space:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.Management;
```

Then use the code below:

```
 CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount =
     cloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue
         (wadConnectionString));

 RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager =   
            cloudStorageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager
            (RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);
```

I just tested above code with SDK 1.8 & Storage Client 2.0.

Comment: The original post says that it was broken by an upgrade, not by a missing namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, as *CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager* extension references an old *CloudStorageAccount*. The workaround would be to use *DeploymentDiagnosticManager*

```
var storageConnectionString = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(
                   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString");
var deploymentDiagnosticManager = new DeploymentDiagnosticManager(
                                      storageConnectionString,
                                      RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId);
return deploymentDiagnosticManager.GetRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(
                        RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
                        RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);`
```

In addition to *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage* you need to reference an old *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient*, as AzureDiagnostics references that assembly.